# exercise oriented to define $a^{x}$ for $a, x$ real numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

This exercise is oriented to define $a^{x}$ for $a, x$ real numbers

Let $s_{n}$, $r_{n}$ two sequences of rational numbers that converges to $x$, then there exist a real number $L$ such that $a^{s_{n}}$ $a^{r_{n}}$ converges to L.

We then define $a^{x}=L$

Any help.

Comment: It helps if you explain why / where you're stuck and what you've tried.

Comment: $s_{n}$, $r_{n}$ two sequences of rational numbers, that confuses me. I dont know how use it, why cant be sequences of reals numbers?

Comment: Presumably you've already defined what $a^x$ means when $x$ is a rational number, but not when $x$ is a real number.  So using sequences of arbitrary real numbers doesn't help, because you can't yet take $a$ to the power of the terms in the sequence.

Comment: They can't be sequences of arbitrary reals because you are trying to *define* exponentiation for arbitrary reals. The point is, you have already (presumably) defined exponentiation for rational exponents; now you use that to define it for arbitrary real exponents.

Comment: oh, I didn't realize that we can use the definition of exponentiation for rational exponents...

Comment: still have problems to prove the result...

Comment: If $s_{n}$, $r_{n}$ are monotone, i can apply the monotone convergence theorem (because $a^{r_{n}}, a^{s_{n}}$, are monotone), right? But they are not monotone sequences, can I work with monotone subsequences?

Answer (score 0):

What needs to be proved is that if $a\gt0$ is real, and $r_n$ is a convergent sequence of rationals, then $a^{r_n}$ is a convergent sequence of reals; also, that if $r_n$ and $s_n$ are sequences of rationals converging to the same limit, then $a^{r_n}$ and $a^{s_n}$ converge to the same limit.

The proofs have to be based on the definition of $a^{p/q}$ for rational $p/q$. The definition of $a^p$ for integer $p$ is easy; then $a^{1/q}$ is defined as the inverse function to $a^q$ (that is, $(a^{1/q})^q=(a^q)^{1/q}=a$); then $a^{p/q}$ is defined as $(a^p)^{1/q}$.

What you do from there is a bit longer than I'm prepared to type out here, but you'll find it done at this [link](http://www.webskate101.com/webnotes/class16.htmld/class16.html).

Comment: I read the information in the link, and l still dont know what is the property that makes de secuences $s_{n}$, $r_{n}$ convergent to the same limit. If $s_{n}$, $r_{n}$ are monotone, i can apply the monotone convergence theorem (I think) but they are not monotone sequences

Comment: The link takes a somewhat different approach to proving the main result, that you can define $a^x$ for real $x$ as a limit of $a^{p/q}$ for appropriate rationals $p/q$. It seems like a slicker approach than the one about sequences converging to the same limit. I bet if you understand the approach in the link, you can work out how to modify it to make the sequences-converging-to-the-same-limit approach work as well.